# How to select specific fragment from the whole text?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

After registering on the site, I receive the credentials by mail in the format:

> **some text /
>   login: example@mail.com /
>   password: example123 /
>   some text**

I need to select and copy exactly the login and password without too much text. All text is located in one table . No idea how to do this. I will be very grateful for the idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could either split the string (quick and dirty):

```
        String input = "some text / login: example@mail.com / password: example123 / some text";
       // iterate over lines if necessary or join using a stream.join("\n")
       String username = input.split("login: ").split(" ")[0];
       String password = input.split("password: ").split(" ")[0];
```

There are probably many other ways others can suggest also.

or use a regex and pattern match:

```
        String input = "some text / login: example@mail.com / password: example123 / some text";
        String emailRegex = "login: .*@.*\\..* ";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String loginEmail = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(matchingText); // would need to split it
        }
```

Do the same for password.

If you want something that's scalable, easier to manage, use Regex. If you're not concerned about performance I think the first option is relatively straight forward but if the email format changes majorly you may need to maintain it.